# Bootstrap Modal shows up on one page but not the other?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to code a website using Bootstrap. I already have it implemented on one page using a modal ([here](http://tempzircon.ga/banman)) and the other page doesn't seem to show the modal ([here](http://tempzircon.ga/banman/functions/ban.php?id=1))  on that page, there is a button that can edit the ban details but when I click the edit button, it does nothing.

Also, I am using jQuery for form submissions so that I can redirect to the returned ID, however, I am stuck on how my function can return the ID because using 
`get_mysql()->fetch_assoc($result)["id"]`
causes a 500 internal server error.
Codes can be found below.

**ban.php**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Ban</h4>
                </div>
                <form id="form">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $ban["uuid"] ?>" id="uuid" name="uuid" placeholder="UUID" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $ban["reason"] ?>" id="reason" name="reason" placeholder="Reason" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $ban["id"] ?>" />
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#form").submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var uuid = $("#uuid").val();
                var reason = $("#reason").val();
                $.post("add.php", { id: id, uuid: uuid, reason: reason, key: "<?php echo get_key() ?>" }, function(data) {
                    location.href = "ban.php?id=<?php echo data ?>";
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**index.php**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Add Ban</h4>
                </div>
                <form id="form">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $ban["uuid"] ?>" id="uuid" name="uuid" placeholder="UUID" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $ban["reason"] ?>" id="reason" name="reason" placeholder="Reason" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#form").submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var uuid = $("#uuid").val();
                var reason = $("#reason").val();
                $.post("functions/add.php", { uuid: uuid, reason: reason, key: "<?php echo get_key() ?>" }, function(data) {
                    location.href = "functions/ban.php?id=<?php echo data ?>";
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**api.php**

```
    <?php
define("key", "redacted");

function get_mysql() {
    $mysql = new mysqli("localhost", "redacted", "redacted", "redacted");
    if($mysql->connect_error) {
        die($mysql->connect_error);
    }
    return $mysql;
}

function add($uuid, $reason) {
    $date = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    get_mysql()->query("insert into bans (uuid, date, reason) values ('$uuid', '$date', '$reason')");
    $result = get_mysql()->query("select id from bans where uuid = '$uuid' and date = '$date' and reason = '$reason'");
    get_mysql()->fetch_array($result);
    return $result["id"];
}

function update($id, $uuid, $reason) {
    get_mysql()->query("update bans set uuid = '$uuid', reason = '$reason' where id = $id");
}

function remove($uuid) {
    get_mysql()->query("delete from bans where uuid = '$uuid'");
}

function remove_by_id($id) {
    get_mysql()->query("delete from bans where id = $id");
}

function get($uuid) {
    return get_mysql()->query("select * from bans where uuid = '$uuid'")->fetch_assoc();
}

function get_by_id($id) {
    return get_mysql()->query("select * from bans where id = $id")->fetch_assoc();
}

function get_bans() {
    return get_mysql()->query("select * from bans");
}

function login($username, $password) {
    $password = hash("sha256", $password);
    return get_mysql()->query("select count(*) from users where username = '$username' and password = '$password'")->num_rows > 0;
}

function register($username, $password) {
    $password = hash("sha256", $password);
    get_mysql()->query("insert into `users` (`username`, `password`) values ('$username', '$password'");
}

function get_key() {
    return key;
}
?>
```

Comment: your second link (the one with the edit button) doesn't seem to load bootstrap. console throws up `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` for `http://tempzircon.ga/banman/functions/js/bootstrap.min.js`

Comment: (facepalm) Thanks @stain88!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer thanks to @stain88. I didn't provide the correct link to bootstrap.min.js (facepalm)

Thanks again @stain88.